# How to achieve target Field with regex in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium, testng

I am using selenium and I am using xpath in target value .

I have a table and I need to count the number of rows.

For example I have an X path starting from `//tr[2]/td/span/input` to `//tr[10]/td/span/input`. Now I want to count the number of X path count by `VerifyXpathCount`.

I need to supply a regex in the Target field of Selenium like `//tr[(*)]/td/span/input`

I am not able to apply such regex so I need to add some regex.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int cnt = selenium.getXpathCount("//tr[/td/span/input]");
```

//to deal with all element

```
for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++){
String loc = "//tr["+i+"]/td/span/input";
//use loc 
}
```

in case if you want to find unique element than you can use other conditions with //tr[/td/span/input] instead of looping

Answer (score 0):

try    `//tr[./td/span/input]` or     `//tr[//td/span/input]` to get/verify xpath count

Comment: you need to get count using one of above way and then iterate for each element. for instance, see comment below